# When I press second time on the button , the app stops working

Tags: java, android, android-studio, authentication, button

I am developing an app that consist of login-register app . In my login activity i have 2 buttons: LOGIN and REGISTER .The Register button is used to redirect you from login activity to register activity . The app works fine till I press once again . The app stops working.

```java
final Button button = (Button) findViewById (R.id.button);
button.setOnClickListener (new View.OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick (View v){
            Intent launchactivity = new Intent (Login.this,Register.class);
            startActivity (launchactivity);
        });
```

Comment: please provide your error log, so that we can identify what's go wrong with your code..

Comment: Question is not clear! Please provide a log error.

Comment: com.example.scooterzapp E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.scooterzapp, PID: 17958

Comment: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.scooterzapp/com.example.scooterzapp.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.Button.setOnClickListener(android.view.View$OnClickListener)' on a null object reference

Comment: at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2325)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2387)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)

Comment: at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.Button.setOnClickListener(android.view.View$OnClickListener)' on a null object reference

Comment: at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5990)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1106)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2278)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2387) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303)

Comment: at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)

Answer (score 0):

try to change from Login.This to getApplicationContext()

```
public void onClick (View v){
   Intent launchactivity = new Intent (getApplicationContext(),Register.class);
   startActivity (launchactivity);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

remove you login.this and add `getApplicationContext()`